# Concat two dataframes and create multi-index from indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

**I have** two DataFrames `df_1` and `df_2` are:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"A1":"1", "A2":"2", "A3":"3"}, index=[2411])
df_1.index.name = "i_1"
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"B1":"4", "B2":"5", "B3":"6"}, index=[123122])
df_2.index.name = "i_2"
```

**I want** to concat them, so the final DataFrames will look like:

```
                A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
i_1     i_2                     
2411    123122  1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Basicly, that's concatination along axis 1 and mooving the setting a multi-index from indexes.

The most closest to the desired result, that i have done is:

```
df_1 = df_1.reset_index()
df_2 = df_2.reset_index()
df_f = pd.concat([df_1,df_2], axis=1)
df_f = pd.DataFrame(df_f, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([float(df_1["i_1"]), float(df_2["i_2"])], names=["i_1","i_2"]))
del df_f["i_1"]
del df_f["i_2"]
```

But the result is:

```
A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
i_1 i_2                     
2411.0  123122.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simpliest is [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) of both `df` for default indexes, so [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) align data nice and last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df_f = pd.concat([df_1.reset_index(),df_2.reset_index()], axis=1).set_index(['i_1','i_2'])
print (df_f)
            A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
i_1  i_2                     
2411 123122  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

In you solution is problem different indexes, so after `concat` get 2 rows, because data cannot allign (not same indexes):

```
df_f = pd.concat([df_1,df_2], axis=1)
print (df_f)
         A1   A2   A3   B1   B2   B3
2411      1    2    3  NaN  NaN  NaN
123122  NaN  NaN  NaN    4    5    6
```

Then get `NaN`s because in `DataFrame` constructor create new `Multiindex` but data not aligne again - in original `df_f` are data size `(2x6)` and want assign to `1,6` structure, also indexes are different.

Comment: Thanks! Could you, please, explain, why does my solution consist of `NaN`'s?